# Call button click event from one web form to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, web-applications

I am developing a web application.which contains multiple web forms.
What i need is :-one of my web form contains IFrame (which will open another aspx page with few Textbox and button controls) with close button.

```
    If i click on the button in the child form(Iframe form), once complete its action it should call the close button function of the parent form.

here is the code.
```

Parent form code

```
protected void BTNCClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MethodToExecute();
            }
            public void MethodToExecute() //call this method
            {
                UPCCharges.Update();
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["CCost"] != null)
                {
                    TxtCCost.Text = Session["CCost"].ToString();
                }
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["CYeild"] != null)
                {
                    TxtCYeild.Text = Session["CYeild"].ToString();
                }
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["CName"] != null)
                {
                    TxtCName.Text = Session["CName"].ToString();
                }
                if (TxtCName.Text != "" && TxtCYeild.Text != "" && TxtCCost.Text != "")
                {
                    TxtCrJobId.Text = Session["CJobID"].ToString();
                    Session.Remove("CCost"); Session.Remove("CYeild");
                    Session.Remove("CName"); Session.Remove("CJobID");

                }
                Diva.Visible = false;
                IFMC.Visible = false;

            }
```

and this is child form(inside the IFrame)

```
protected void BTNCCloseChild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
    for (int vLoop2 = 0; vLoop2 < gvInner.Items.Count; vLoop2++)
    {
       if (TxtTotalCFrom1 != null && TxtTotalCFrom2 != null)
       {
           TextBox TxtTotalCFrom = (TextBox)gvInner.Items[vLoop2].FindControl("TxtTCFrom");
           TextBox TxtTotalCYeild = (TextBox)gvInner.Items[vLoop2].FindControl("TxtTCYeild");
           Session["CCost"] = (mobjGenlib.ConvertDecimal(TxtTFrom1.Text) + mobjGenlib.ConvertDecimal(TxtTFrom2.Text)).ToString();
           Session["CYeild"] = (mobjGenlib.ConvertDecimal(TxtRO.Text) - mobjGenlib.ConvertDecimal(TxtTFrom.Text)).ToString();
           Session["CName"] = gvInner.Items.Count.Items[vLoop2].Cells[1].Text;
           Session["CJobID"] = gvInner.Items.Count.Items[vLoop2].Cells[2].Text;
       }
    }

 //after this i want to call that parent form BTNCClose_Click
}
```

can any one help me to solve this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way that you can handle

in the `BTNCCloseChild_Click` event of the child form, add the following code at the end

```
string script =@"$('the selector of your parent window button',
                    window.parent.document).click();";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CloseParent", script);
```

You have to change the 'the selector of your parent window button', to appropreate jquery selector to uniquely select the button of the parent form.

You may have to use `window.top` instead of `window.parent`, if there are nested iframes.

Answer (score -2):

Add this line:

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "script",  " parent.location.href = parent.location.href;", false);

after this or instead of this
 //after this i want to call that parent form BTNCClose_Click

After storing the values in session object it will refresh the parent page and the values will be updated.