# Web application which is working in firefox,chrome and ie8 is not opening in IE10 ,IE11

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

I developed an Web Application which is working fine in all other browser even in IE8 but not working in Latest version of IE like IE10,IE11.
In IE11 on button click it throws an error like "**Input string was not in a correct format**" but in IE8 and other browser it was working without any error.

In IE11 if i press F12 and see in DOM Explorer it throws error as:
**exception in window.onload js plugin.3005-Inprogress.**

can any one help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

On button click i am getting the error.but if i keep break point in the button click and check .i found that the click  event not fired in IE11

> hi now i found that the error was occuring at the time of
>   scriptmanager postback.
>
> this is the code

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"
        ScriptMode="Release" OnAsyncPostBackError="ScriptManager1_AsyncPostBackError" />
```

[image]

Comment: Want to share the line of code that is actually throwing that error?  Otherwise, I'm not sure how we can help.  Use F12 to get to the Debugger.

Comment: Actually the same code was working in IE8 and other browser but in IE11 getting error...if i keep break point and check means none of the thing returning error.but in global.aspx page i am getting an error as Input string was not in a correct format i am not sure form where it is returning..

Comment: On button click i am getting the error in global.aspx page

Comment: Nobody but you has any idea what error you are getting, or what is in your global.aspx page.  Also, the error message that you list in your question is a JavaScript error, not a server-side error.  You added your sever-side button click code.  How is that relevant to the error?

Comment: but for that button click i have not wrote any javascript.i am getting error once the is button click only

Comment: Set your debugger to break on all exceptions `Ctrl` `Alt`+`E`, check Thrown for Common Language Runtime Exceptions.  Let us know exactly what line throws the exception.

Comment: Ok thanks for your advice let me check and let you know

Comment: You are not providing enough information. Your error is in a javascript library and my guess is that you don't know where it is even loaded. Back up one step.  Go to a browser that works - FF.  Press F12 and view the Console tab. If there are any javascript related issues they will show up there.  Other good check is the Network tab to diagnose what libraries are loading or not.

Comment: I checked using f12 but in console and debugger but nothing gets displayed..all i get is in DOM explorer tab it displays the following execption "exception in window.onload js plugin.3005-Inprogress."

Comment: your button handler is c# (server side code) but you are describing a client side error; are you seeing the exception on the server or in the browser?  checking with F12 is going to show you errors in the dynamic javascript that you did not write; it's unlikely the error is in that code.

Comment: also, you aren't listing enough of the .aspx page here; the problem is likely in one of your html elements in the form, not with the button itself.

Comment: I am seeing the exception in the F12 under DOM exception.In browser when i click the button nothing is happens just displaying the screen instead of loading the grid.Let me check the aspx page.

Comment: but in other browser it was working fine in IE11 alone getting same error in all my forms.

Comment: If I Removed the scriptmanager and the UpdatePanel the application was working fine in IE11 also.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Flowwing script in the aspx page solved my issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._origOnFormActiveElement = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._onFormElementActive;
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._onFormElementActive = function (element, offsetX, offsetY) {
if (element.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT' && element.type === 'image') {
offsetX = Math.floor(offsetX);
offsetY = Math.floor(offsetY);
}
this._origOnFormActiveElement(element, offsetX, offsetY);
};
</script>
```